# Why keyword this work with static methods?

Tags: javascript

```
class StaticMethodCall {
      static staticMethod() {
        return 'Static method has been called';
      }
      static anotherStaticMethod() {
        return this.staticMethod() + ' from another static method';
      }
    }
    StaticMethodCall.staticMethod(); 
    // 'Static method has been called'

    StaticMethodCall.anotherStaticMethod(); 
    // 'Static method has been called from another static method'
```

Why this work ? I expected fatal error in this case before.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static#From_another_static_method

Comment: I copy past from then i know..... fun comment

Comment: *I expected fatal error in this case before* - why would you expect that? You can even write `this` in a top-level function, like `function test(x){this.something=x;}`, and it will do something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in JS is not the same as `this` in the likes of an actual OO language like Java etc. Where `this` in the likes of java refers to the current object of a class, in JS there are no 'classes', `this` in JS just refers to a current context scope, which may be, in your case, a 'static' method on a 'class', which will essentially boil down to being the current scope of a plain old object

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function via a reference like `someobject.property()`, the `this` value will be set to `someobject`. That's a basic feature of the language. Static methods are properties of the constructor function, so when you call them via a reference to the constructor the value of `this` will be that function.

Answer (score 1):

In languages like Java, the static methods belong to a class rather than an instance so when you use `this` inside `static` method you get an compilation *error* as the method doesn't know which instance to refer to (as there could be many instances of the class).

But the `class` is just a syntactic sugar for the JavaScript `function` object, so when you call `StaticMethodCall.anotherStaticMethod();` here `this` will point to the context of the `StaticMethodCall` `class` object which is nothing but a `function` object under the hood. JavaScript functions are also objects which can have properties declared on them. So when you use a constructor function (es6 class) you could declare properties on the function object which is nothing but the `static` in es6.

Let me explain this way, the following code is what is happening under the hood if you transpile it to es5 through Babel:

```js
//This is what static means in es6 class. they are properties of the constructor function
function StaticMethodCall(){ //This represents your class
}
StaticMethodCall.staticMethod = function(){
  return 'Static method has been called';
}
StaticMethodCall.anotherStaticMethod = function(){
  return this.staticMethod() + ' from another static method';
}
console.log(StaticMethodCall.staticMethod()); 
// StaticMethodCall is a reference to the class object, this points to.
console.log(StaticMethodCall.anotherStaticMethod());
```

Here when you define `static` methods on es6 classes the methods are added as properties of the constructor function so when you call the static method with the reference of the class `StaticMethodCall` this is actually pointing to that `class/function` object.

So `this` is not the same as you would expect in Java, where you cannot refer to `this` inside a static context as it does not know which object to refer to (as classes are not objects). In Java, classes are not actually objects like JavaScript.

Another way to verify that es6 `class` is actually a `function` is by using the `typeof`:

```js
class StaticMethodCall{
}
console.log(typeof StaticMethodCall); //outputs "function"
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand it better you should check the transpiled code from 
[Babel](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDKAuZ4EtgFkCm8AWB7AJgMJggjQDeAUNDbRIisNPUqpjgQBQCUF1tAgE5YAroIB20AOQJWTALZY8-aNkjQARhgyTgJEBnxSA3PwEBfM3QapoYcbhwZBsxu2U8-AoaInQcyBAAdCxuSly8ANTS0ABmgrjydg5Ogsw2CuFGpt7QljQAkDQO4q6onlS50MLwYpJSJelyJtBWNPm0lkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=true&targets=&version=7.5.5&externalPlugins=)

the scope of static functions is the same scope of the class (that compiled is a `Constructor` function).

Static functions are declared as properties on the `Constructor` function, whether normal functions are declared as properties on the `Constructor.prototype` and are available consequently on all the instances.